# how to determine the cpu units and memory limit values for a container/task to be deployed in ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, docker-container

I have few applications to be deployed in ECS with launch type fargate.
How to determine the no.of cpu units and memory required for an application , what are the parameters i need to considers for this?, Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately this will come down to testing and validating your applications resource usage. You need to consider whether your application is CPU or memory heavy, this will help guide some initial estimations.

I would suggest that you perform some basic load testing against each container to try and determine its bounds. Try to keep this testing realistic whilst accounting for near term growth.

When you have these figures set these as limits within your containers task definition. Keep an eye on these over the first few days of rollout and you should get an idea of how realistic these values are. You can then start right-sizing as you get more of an idea over the applications are performing.

If in doubt give it more than you think it requires during launch. You can always adjust later as you become more confident in the boundaries.

Take a look at AWS general [Tips for Right-Sizing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/cost-optimization-right-sizing/tips-for-right-sizing-your-workloads.html) which might help to inform decisions. These are fairly general for most AWS services.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and tips,  if the provided cpu/memory is not sufficient for the container/application to run , would ECS kills the container? .

Comment: Not as far as I am aware, it just caps the maximum resource that a user can get (this is the benefit of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups). Soft limits will always reserve an amount but if the underlying resource has more available it can take (as long as there is not contention with other resources), whereas hard limits would make it so that the resource can never attain more than this.

Comment: in case of fargate,  i understood that dedicated linux kernel is allocated to each task and resources cannot be shared among tasks  , in this case what happens when application goes beyond the memory hard limit or needs more CPU, would it slows down the application or restarts the container or kills the container or  the action to be taken is based on any policy settings? , i am just trying to understand the impact at runtime if the provided resources are not sufficient and how ECS takes care of it with fargate launch .

Comment: For Fargate the maximum resources available are bound to the task size (this can also be specified in standard ECS but is optional). So containers cannot exceed this resource amount. They won't be replaced unless the container healthcheck actually fails, it won't be possible to go above the hard limits it simply caps resources (similar to burstable resources like T instances).